# Why does my checkall function not work?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I am working with MVC using php, jquery and html. In my views page i have code that calls a function which creates a list of checkboxes depending on certain parameters and a javascript function that checks all the boxes when the function is called and the all button is checked by the user.
The part below calls the function with id or ward.

```
 <?=form_label('Wards  : ')?> <span id="wards"></span>
```

The part below executes the checkall boxes.

```
$('#checkall').change(function(){

    if($(this).prop('checked')){
     //uncheck all the checkboxes   
     $("input.w:checkbox").each( 
       function() { 
          $(this).prop('checked',true);
       } 
     );
   }else{
      //check all the checkboxes  
      $("input.w:checkbox").each( 
       function() { 
          $(this).prop('checked',false);
       } 
     ); 
   }
});
```

This is the Ward Function that produces the check boxes.

```
public function wards(){
        $id = $this->input->post('id');

        $this->db->join('building', 'building.id = ward.building_id');
        $this->db->select('ward.*, building.name as building_name');
        $this->db->where_in('ward.building_id', explode(',',$id));
        $sql = $this->db->get('ward');  
        $wards = $sql->result();

        $editid = $this->uri->segment(3);

        $this->db->select('wards');
        $userwards = $this->db->get_where('users', array('id'=>$editid))->result();

        $userwards = explode(',', $userwards[0]->wards);
        $data = array('name'=> 'wards[]', 'id'=> 'checkall', 'value' => 'All Observations','style'  => 'float: left; margin-right: 10px'); 
        if(!empty($wards)){
        echo form_checkbox($data).' '.form_label('All Wards');
            foreach($wards as $w){
                if(in_array($w->id, $userwards)){
                    $checked = 'TRUE';  
                } else { $checked = ''; }
                $warddata = array('name'=> 'wards[]', 'value' => $w->id, 'class' => 'w', 'checked'=> $checked, 'style'  => 'float: left; margin-right: 10px'); 
                echo                
                form_checkbox($warddata).' '.form_label($w->name.' ('.$w->building_name.')');   
            }
        }
        else { echo '<font color="#c00">No Wards are assigned to this building!</font>';}

    }
```

So the checkboxes are produced as expected but when i check the all wards checkbox the other boxes do not become checked. What have i done wrong?

Comment: We don't need your PHP code, please show us your rendered HTML instead. Ideally put all this in a jsFiddle too.

Comment: Is your jQuery code actually firing? Did you wrap it in a document load event?

Comment: Incidentally, you can shorten your jQuery code to: `$('#checkall').change(function(){ $("input.w:checkbox").prop('checked',$(this).prop('checked'));});` -- http://jsfiddle.net/mblase75/dr77M/

Answer (score 0):

Just in case you made the most common jQuery mistake:

Did you wrap your jQuery in a document load/ready event?

The old syntax was `$(document).ready(function(){...});` but the newer version is simply `$(function(){...});`

e.g.

```
$(function(){
    $('#checkall').change(function(){

        if($(this).prop('checked')){
         //uncheck all the checkboxes   
         $("input.w:checkbox").each( 
           function() { 
              $(this).prop('checked',true);
           } 
         );
       }else{
          //check all the checkboxes  
          $("input.w:checkbox").each( 
           function() { 
              $(this).prop('checked',false);
           } 
         ); 
       }
    });
});
```

Failing that, check if you code is firing with something simple like an `alert`:

e.g.

```
    $('#checkall').change(function(){
        alert("Yes, it fired!");   // Use liberally while developing :)        
        if($(this).prop('checked')){
```

Failing all that, try viewing your page in Google Chrome with the F12 debug window open.

It will list any Javascript/jQuery errors found and you can breakpoint code, view contents of variables etc.

As PHP is pretty much a *write-only language*, questions like this need to show the HTML output it generates as well, preferably in a JSFiddle with your jQuery.